# suggest any way to make executables build on 64 run on 32 bit ubuntu

Tags: linux, 64-bit, executable, 32bit-64bit

I had an executable and source code of software made on 64 bit linux want to make that executable run on  32 bit linux. How it can be done in how many ways any easy process

Thankss

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to virtualize a 64bits Linux on Virtualbox for example.
But your processor must have a 64bit architecture and support virtualization...